# What would be the best way to power a mecha?

Tags: internal-consistency, nuclear, nuclear-weapons, nuclear-power, mechs

While searching around, I kept hearing that fusion was a good choice, but how best to covert the energy to electricity was an issue.

However, during my research, I came across [this:](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon-intermediate_direct_energy_conversion)

> Photon-intermediate direct energy conversion (PIDEC) is somewhat similar to a concept of fluorescent light - as in the CFL, in the nuclear reactor the original type of energy generated is not useful to humans. CFL uses a fluorescent coating on the inside of the light bulb to convert that energy into visible spectrum of the light. PIDEC uses fluorescer (in the form of gas) surrounding nuclear fuel acting as photon producer - fluorescer gets excited by neutron emissions and in turn emits narrow band ultraviolet light. That light is then relatively easily converted into electricity by special photo-voltaic converter.
>
> Because the photons emitted by fluorescer are narrow band, the conversion efficiency is much higher than efficiency of common solar cells. The overall efficiency of PIDEC is expected to be around 40%. The remaining residual heat is still high enough to use it in traditional thermalized way via Carnot Cycle e.g. steam turbine. A combined efficiency of such conversion system (PIDEC + traditional) could reach as much as 70%. In comparison, due to limitations of using solid nuclear fuel and water as coolant, current generation of nuclear plants average only about 35% conversion efficiency.

Now as explained [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=UtBKDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA97&lpg=PA97&dq=diamond%20photovoltaic%20cells%20as%20a%20first%20wall%20material%20and%20Energy%20Conversion%20System%20for%20Inertial%20Confinement%20Fusion&source=bl&ots=86TJUSb436&sig=ACfU3U0k_vMlChcSQjon5gLJowaJDyVs3Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSjZjNpZnnAhWhnOAKHQj0BvEQ6AEwCHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=diamond%20photovoltaic%20cells%20as%20a%20first%20wall%20material%20and%20Energy%20Conversion%20System%20for%20Inertial%20Confinement%20Fusion&f=false), PIDAC was conceived for use in high temperature fusion reactors.

In addition, [it is shown as capable of also generating power from fission and radioisotopes](https://books.google.com/books?id=ggHoCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA469&dq=photon-intermediate%20direct%20energy%20conversion&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNhousnpnnAhVooFkKHTI7BiAQ6AEIQjAE#v=onepage&q=photon-intermediate%20direct%20energy%20conversion&f=false)

During my research into this concept I came across this study: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/014919709090003N

> A two-step photon-intermediate technique for the production of electricity, chemicals or lasers in nuclear energy conversion
>
> In addition to electric power, photolysis makes other product forms possible. These products include useful feedstock, or combustion chemicals, such as hydrogen and carbon monoxide, and excited molecular and atomic states, used for laser amplifiers or oscillators.

Interesting...I mention this as it reminds me of how Mark Simmons describes how Gundams and Zakus generate both power, propulsion, and even their beam weaponry: http://www.ultimatemark.com/gundam/power.html

> Since electrical generation, propulsion, and cooling all involve extracting thermal energy from the reactor and transferring it to other parts of the mobile suit's body, why not use the same mechanism for all three? The author imagines a network of thermal energy conduits running throughout the mobile suit's body, transferring reactor heat via high-pressure helium gas (8). This provides a handy explanation for the cables and tubes that decorate the exteriors of our favorite mobile suits (9).
>
> The classic MS-06 Zaku II. In the author's opinion, its trademark power cables are most likely used to transfer thermal energy for propulsion, electrical generation, and cooling purposes. This theory is, however, at odds with the official explanation (10).

Here are his footnotes fyi:

> (8) Entertainment Bible 1: One Year War Picture Encyclopedia identifies helium as the coolant used in the MS-06 Zaku II. Since this is also a suitable medium for transferring reactor heat to generator turbines, and its relatively low molecular weight makes it an efficient propellant for thermonuclear rocket engines, it seems like a good candidate for all three applications. Plus, this would explain the significance of the mysterious "helium control cores" attached to the Gundam's skirt armor!
>
> (9) For example, the Master Grade GM Custom kit manual explains that the cables that run down the back of the mobile suit's legs supply energy to its leg thrusters.
>
> (10) The official explanation for the Zaku II's cables is that they transmit hydraulic power to actuators in the mobile suit's joints. This always struck me as absurd, for why would the Zaku need to transmit hydraulic power from its belly to its backback, or from its muzzle to the back of its head? Likewise, early mobile suits like the Zaku II and the Gundam are usually said to use traditional chemical rocket engines, but this seems to defeat the purpose of having a thermonuclear reactor in the first place.

Now while Mark's explanation makes sense, it seems to me that PIDAC fulfils a very similar design.

For example a similar form of propulsion to Mobile Suits using PIDEC would be based on the concept: ["Nuclear Lightbulb" concept](https://books.google.com/books?id=Y7DLDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA134&lpg=PA134&dq=nuclear%20lightbulb%20pidec&source=bl&ots=_cHeeS6932&sig=ACfU3U23nZcrOUYkwuCQzbOCYW_nNgrDOA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj_9YXxrJnnAhWQdd8KHY3wDT0Q6AEwBHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=nuclear%20lightbulb%20pidec&f=false)

As someone else put it: https://space.stackexchange.com/a/27372

> The idea is that you operate a fission reactor in a gas (really plasma) phase inside a transparent pressure vessel. The fissionables might be mixed with a fluorescing compound. If you run the reactor hot enough, radiation (which scales with the fourth power of temperature) becomes the dominant mode of energy transfer, primarily in the form of UV light. You pass your reaction mass - likely hydrogen doped with something to improve its UV absorption - over the outside of the reactor vessel. It's heated by the UV, conceptually to much higher temperatures than possible with solid core NTRs.
>
> The concept hinges on the reactor vessel being so perfectly transparent to UV radiation that you can pass gigawatts of UV light through it without it absorbing them and therefore heating and melting. Additionally you need to run a plasma-phase fission reaction inside it (good luck with your neutron economy) and somehow protect it from that ferociously hot and corrosive material.

I am pretty sure he isn't right about the reaction mass needing to be passed over the outside of the vessel. It's all internal. At least it hasn't come up in the official scientific documentation.
He also mentions heat would be a problem, but again thermal conversion is compatible with PIDEC.
[Not to mention there seems to be a way around the radiation damage issue](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0969804317308564)

Back to Mark's article

> However, this doesn't account for all of the cables. Mobile suits also need to transmit beam energy, in the form of Minovsky particles, to their weapons. The Gundam's beam rifle and beam saber both contain energy capacitors, which store the high-energy Minovsky particles used to form their devastating beams. In the case of the beam rifle, electrical power from the mobile suit's generators is used to convert the stored Minovsky particles into massive, fast-moving mega particles prior to firing.

Interesting isn't it. Especially since PIDEC also seems to be very useful for the making of [Nuclear-Pumped lasers](https://books.google.com/books?id=Hmn_CgAAQBAJ&pg=PA415&dq=photon-intermediate%20direct%20energy%20conversion&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjNhousnpnnAhVooFkKHTI7BiAQ6AEIOjAD#v=onepage&q=photon-intermediate%20direct%20energy%20conversion&f=false) under a similar principle.
(See p.107 in the google book link for reference)

I do think that if we ever make fusion powered mecha, this would be the best option, especially with recent breakthroughs in photovoltaics: https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms14962

Is this energy conversion scheme plausible?

Comment: That's a huge wall of text... First of all, define best: a Lamborghini Camargo can be the best on German highways, but drop it in a Dutch canal and see how it fares. Then, give us a problem to solve. We give solutions, not opinions/thoughts.

Comment: I'd love to see how hydrogen could be "doped". Perhaps your question could ask about the limitations of a proposed PIDEC system re size, mass, longevity, fragility, suitability, maintenance etc..

Comment: That came from another guy who I don't think is as smart as he thinks he is.

Comment: @Bitterdreggs. the usual term is "seeded". Something like 1-10% of the reaction mass will need to be something that's good at absorbing heat and UV. The couple of papers I have here on gas-core nuclear rockets don't bother investigating what the seed particles would be, but note that they would be required to ensure adequate transfer of heat to the working fluid and to prevent the outer wall of the reaction chamber from being incinerated.

Comment: @Bitterdreggs. aha: [this paper](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19920001892.pdf) suggests the seed particles could be made from very finely ground tungsten dust.

Comment: @JacobBlaustein what he said looks quite reasonable to me.

Comment: I also note that you have 5 other questions over the last six months, some of which have highly upvoted answers, none of which you've accepted. It would be nice if you accepted some or more of those answers, or updated your questions to state why the existing answers are inadequate.

Comment: @StarfishPrime It's making a lot more sense now, that paper's a good find. Thanks.

Comment: @StarfishPrime Thanks for the paper man.

Comment: Well for a start engines don't use thermal energy by itself, they use a thermal energy DIFFERENTIAL. heating up the whole mech removes that differential.

Comment: PART 1; **One critical point has not been addressed by the poster;**
And that is the actual power requirements of the mech in question. How many kilowatts of power required to operate the mech in combat. That it turn is based on basic system specs like the size and weight of mech, required ground speed, type and number of weapons carried (lasers would require much more power to operate than say a conventional auto cannon or missile pack etc.) and endurance. How long is the mech required to remain operational in the field.

Comment: PART 2: For example the mechs from Mech Warrior are huge, mount powerful energy weapons etc and are powered (from memory by mico fusion reactors or some such). The mechs in Heavy Gear are small and almost never mount any kind of energy weapon and as a result their power requirements can be met by a back pack mounted internal combustion engine. So they need to set out their parameters of their mech before people can start speculating about how best to power it.

Comment: This is a really good analysis of the proposed system, well researched and documented, but there is no real question. At best, I could see this as being turned into a 'reality check' question if a particular solution were posited.

Answer (score 10):

So, crawling through that wall-o-text, you seem to be proposing a closed-cycle gas core nuclear reactor with PIDEC to provide power for a mecha, right?

Lets ignore the weirdness about "transferring thermal energy", it isn't a totally daft idea on the face of things, but:

1. Nuclear fission reactors have a minimal size. The "nuclear lightbulb" rocket designs weigh about 30 tonnes, and were about six metres long.
2. Thats excluding heatsink mass, and those things will generate a *lot* of waste heat. Heatsinking is the bane of realistic spaceship designs, and nuclear giant mecha are no different. Nuclear powered (war)ships can use the sea. The atmosphere isn't nearly as good.
3. It also excludes radiation shielding, and those things are going to be producing quite a lot of that.
4. You can't just turn a nuclear lightbulb off on a whim. And when it is off, you can't just flip a switch and have it come back to life again. This might not bother you.
5. You're building something intended to go into combat, and inside it you have a giant glass bottle full of super high pressure uranium plasma. When one of these things goes boom, and eventually one of them will, it'll be Really, Really Bad News for the local environment, and anyone downwind.

> I am pretty sure he isn't right about the reaction mass needing to be passed over the outside of the vessel. It's all internal.

Don't confuse reaction mass (the working fluid of your rocket or reactor, that you heat up and expel out of a nozzle or run through a turbine) with fuel (the fissile gas on the inside of the lightbulb). In a closed-cycle gas core rocket (or reactor) the working fluid is kept entirely separate.

If you want to use PIDEC, then there is no working fluid to heat (because the UV emitted by the nuclear plasma is directly used by your PIDEC system) but you'll still need to cool the damn thing, and for that you'll want to be running large quantities of high heat-capacity and UV-transparent coolant over the outside of the lightbulb.

> Is this energy conversion scheme plausible?

It is plausible, but not practical. Too much heat, too much radiation.

Honestly, your best bet will be some kind of net-energy-gain hydrogen-boron-11-fuelled athermal fusor. Such a thing may as well be handwavium at this point, but doesn't appear to be impossible... an example of such a device would be a [dense plasma focus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_plasma_focus). Certainly, dense plasma focus devices exist now, though they're no good as power sources, but to my knowledge no-one has ever made something that involves controlled fission in a uranium plasma! The minimum size is much lower than a fission lightbulb, the amount of neutral particle radiation is *vastly* less. Depending on how efficiently you can convert x-rays to electricity, the heat output for a given power output might be less, too. That is something you might be able to do with PIDEC if you felt the need, though I suspect it'll run hot. PIDEC is less handwavium than x-ray-voltaics, at least.

Comment: Thank you for suggesting the dense plasma focus. I did kinda imagine how the reactor would have to compress the fuel source and released energy.

Comment: I am confused by your concerns though. Radiation wouldn't be an issue: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0969804317308564 & as for the heat I would combine the PIDEC w/ radioisotope thermoelectric generators. As for the heat sinks, I would take a page from old school Super Robot Anime and use them to channel the heat towards my foes... are you sure the radiation would still be a problem? I could add betavoltic packs if necessary

Comment: Sorry, scratch the betavoltic packs. As I pointed out in the op, PIDEC is also capable of generating power from fission and radioisotopes: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235574058_Direct_Conversion_of_Nuclear_Energy_to_Electricity

Comment: @JacobBlaustein of _course_ radiation is an issue: you're building a _nuclear reactor_. You have to shield all your electronics, and the pilot, and any nearby friendlies. You're going to get all sorts of unpleasant radiation shooting out. Of course your power extraction hardware needs to be radiation resistant, but how are you going to do the same with the meatbag pilot? Or a complex computer-based AI pilot for that matter? Unless your power extraction mechanism can stop all radiation coming out (and spoiler alert: if it does, it'll be way too big and heavy) it will remain a problem.

Comment: I think we do have a mechanism for just this sort of thing: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/29729484 several in fact: https://mospace.umsystem.edu/xmlui/handle/10355/769 The radiation is converted by the fluorescer medium into photons. It's how it's supposed to work. It's well explained in the links

Comment: @JacobBlaustein If it were better than regular radiation shielding, then people would be using it _as_ radiation shielding. It is not. People do not.You will _still_ need a lot of big, heavy, bulky shielding, because you are operating a _nuclear reactor_ that produces masses of radiation in many, many different flavours, and if you don't shield it your electronics will fail and your meatbags will die.

Comment: @JacobBlaustein I mean, from your first link, you can see that it needs a 6cm tungsten shield just for the gamma rays in _one_ fission byproduct. It does not consider shielding the _actual fission reaction at all_. You still need an entire set of reactor shielding _as well_ as that 6cm tungsten shield for the krypton-85 loop, plus the 12cm thick walls of the pressure vessel it is contained in. All that for only a small proportion of the energy released from the reaction, too. Fine for big static civil reactors. Not great for things that need to be highly mobile.

Comment: @JacobBlaustein the second link only considers the radiation resistance of the photovoltaics in the PIDEC system, which is _essential_ if it were to work at all, but does _not_ consider radiation that escapes the device to affect things outside, and nor does it consider the radiation released by the _actual reactor_.

Comment: ok then. I though the system absorbing and converting the radioisotopes via photatomic reaction would cover it: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0969804317308564.      So why not, and what shielding shoul I use?

Comment: @JacobBlaustein depends on your nuclear reactions. The link you just gave was for alpha particle radiation, which has very low penetration in any material. Beta emitters are similarly easily shielded. It is _everything else_ that's the problem; you should assume that fast neutrons (_especially_ fusion neutrons) and gammma rays have low absorption cross sections and therefore will require lots of shielding mass (either thin and dense, or sparse and deep). Pick your reactor technology first, then the size of your reactor, and then worry about cooling and shielding.

Comment: @Thank you for mentioning this...however am not sure it would be a [problem](https://books.google.com/books?id=UtBKDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA98&lpg=PA98&dq=pidec+gamma&source=bl&ots=86UARMb_29&sig=ACfU3U1bEok-fsQqn4N4LPQ1z0-Zfh-ApQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwinhMXD86vnAhUglXIEHaTSD7IQ6AEwBHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=pidec%20gamma&f=false)

Comment: @JacobBlaustein dude, PIDEC ain't a magic gamma ray forcefield, and it **really, really isn't reactor shielding**. No reactor shielding is considered in any of your links, becaused PIDEC is separate from the reactor. The reactor still needs to be shielded. Even the PIDEC loop needs to be shielded, as some of your links actually describe. **You still need shielding**.

Comment: ok then...would a titanium-gold alloy work for this? https://advances.sciencemag.org/content/2/7/e1600319 Or this one? https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2019/03/190305153653.htm

Comment: @JacobBlaustein this is a different question, and not one suited to a SE comment thread. I've never heard of titanium-gold being proposed for shielding; it sounds unreasonably expensive. Tungsten will be OK for x- and gamma-rays and poor for fast neutrons.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a decentralized array of [Radioisotope thermoelectric generators?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioisotope_thermoelectric_generator)

However, to move giant mechas you would also need really big and efficient batteries to bypass the usage spikes.
Fusion or fission IS possible, but cooling the thing down is an engineering nightmare. If done by gas, it would *not be for impulse*, since less gas = less cooling. And thermal energy can't be used for impulse. To gain momentum you need to launch *something* in the opposite direction, unless you are resorting to technobabble or magic, which is not bad per se, but lacks the reality barnish.

Comment: RTGs are best suited for providing small amounts of power over long periods of time (i.e. decades). Mechas require the exact opposite: large amounts of power for very short periods. I'd remove that line and just concentrate on the second paragraph.

Comment: If you're going with RTGs, you'll need batteries, at which point those batteries could have been charged by any source of electricity, not just an RTG.

Answer (score 0):

Although it doesn't quite follow the nuclear reactor idea, I have a fun suggestion.
Ever heard of vacuum energy? Would something that just kinda scoops that stuff up work?
It could have a nuclear "starter" to get the scoop going, but once it starts up it runs off itself. Only problem is, a lightbulb of vacuum energy could destroy the earth, so maybe they invented ridiculously durable materials first. Makes it even more fun.

Comment: With the `reality-check` tag present, vacuum energy is probably off the table.

Comment: Fair, fair. Although, with mecha and Gundam, reality check means a way to get unholy amounts of energy that's possible or plausible.